# Does AFNetworking 2.0 Supports Background task? - iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

i am using Afnetworking 2.0 library with NSURLSession.

i found in AFURLSessionManager they configure Session with default session , so if i need to download images in background then i have to set Session with Background configuration.

So , I have to change AFNetworking library for that or is there any other way for that in AFNetworking 2.0.

Comment: did you take a look to [UIImageView+AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html)?

Answer (score 3):

From [Using NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html):

> The NSURLSession class supports background transfers while your app is suspended. Background transfers are provided only by sessions created using a background session configuration object (as returned by a call to `backgroundSessionConfiguration:`).

You must configure your AFHTTPSessionManager to use the background session configuration if you want to do this:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.myApp.backgroundDownloadSession"]
AFHTTPSessionManager *backgroundManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
```

AFNetworking will set itself as the delegate.  From the NSURLSession docs:

> [T]he delegate will be retained until after the delegate has been sent the `URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError:` message

As a result, your manager will stick around as long as this session does.

Two side notes:

1. You should probably use use a *separate `AFHTTPSessionManager`* for background transfers (large downloads, etc.)  You don't want literally all requests to be assigned a background URL session.
2. In case you want to retrieve the response without AFNetworking, note what the background session identifier is ('com.myApp.backgroundDownloadSession' in my sample code):

   > An identifier for the new session configuration that is unique for your app. Your app can retrieve the download or the upload response later by creating a new background session with the same identifier.

Comment: @yasirmturk What's iOS 8-only about this solution? `ackgroundSessionConfiguration:` is actually deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: sorry i thought it was `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`

Comment: @yasirmturk That's OK.